# Voting protocol in distributed system

Tags: distributed, voting, distributed-system

I'm learning Distributed Operating System,and I have a question about Voting protocol: "When should I use static voting protocol instead dynamic voting protocol?" (that mean, in any case static voting protocol is better than dynamic voting protocol).

[Link](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~xyuan/cop5611/lecture17.html) to voting protocol.

Comment: This is an algorithmic question. Can you link to an online version of the algorithms pseudocode and/or descriptions? This always helps in getting better answers sooner.

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever both terms are used, *static* = simple, but less flexible than *dynamic* = complex, but can adapt to changing situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [this](http://hssl.cs.jhu.edu/~randal/416/lectures/14.voting.pdf) set of notes on voting protocols:

> 13. Beneﬁts of static voting
>       (a) Simple protocol
>       (b) Little state kept at each site (version number only). Very scalable.
>       (c) Good for static conﬁgurations that are realiable (parallel computers)